# Disable "save" with office addin VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, add-in

I'm making an AppLock for Office and I want to lock features, like open, save and saveas with a password

Can I make something like this?

```
Public Sub ThisAddIn_OnSave(sender As Object, e As SaveEventArgs) Handles Me.OnSave
    If <my_condition> Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Office application you want to integrate with.  For example, in Word you can handle the [Application.DocumentBeforeSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff838299.aspx) event.

Otherwise, you can [intercept Ribbon button commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633.aspx) and execute your custom code that way.

Answer (score 0):

[Repurposing ribbon controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not enought for preventing users from doing such actions.

A keyboard shortcut can be used (for example, Ctrl+S for saving documents). You need to set a keyboard hook for repurposing keyboard shortcuts, see [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/09/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) for more information.